# Dynamically bootstrap popup alerts box through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating popup Bootstrap alert box on button click. 
Problem:- on click popup is not show it will display on page load. I want to show popup alert only onclick.

Here is my code:-

```
**JS:-**
function bootstrap_alert(elem, message, timeout) {
  $(elem).show().html('<div class="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>'+message+'</span></div>');

  if (timeout || timeout === 0) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $(elem).alert('close');
    }, timeout);    
  }
};

<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
        bootstrap_alert('#item-publish','This message will fade out in 1 second', 1000);

  });

</script>

**Html:-**
<a class="btn gray mini mr5" id="item-publish">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
   Publish
 </a>
```

kindly advice me any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your bootstrap_alert function is expecting elem, message, timeout as parameters

```
function bootstrap_alert(elem, message, timeout)
```

but you are not passing elem into it, you need to replace this

```
bootstrap_alert('This message will fade out in 1 second', 1000)
```

with

```
bootstrap_alert('#item-publish','This message will fade out in 1 second', 1000)
```

or put whatever elem you want to select

**Update**

Instead of trying to add the alert dynamically I would add it to the html but set it to hidden

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/au55b990/1/

HTML

```
<div id="alertBox" class="alert alert-info" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <span class="alertMessage"></span>
</div>

<a class="btn gray mini mr5" id="item-publish">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
    Publish
</a>
```

JS

```
function bootstrap_alert(elem, message, timeout) {        
  $(elem + " .alertMessage").text(message)  
  $(elem).show().alert()

  if (timeout || timeout === 0) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $(elem).hide();
    }, timeout);    
  }
};

$('#item-publish').click(function () {
  bootstrap_alert('#alertBox','This message will fade out in 1 second', 1000)
});
```

Comment: I have updated my code. but still i m unable to get popup alert on click